# How to check in Next.js if a dynamic path does not exists and to return 404 after checking in database?

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, http-status-code-404

For example localhost:3000/categories/**1** exists, but localhost:3000/categories/**2** does not exists so to return 404 that page does not exists

```
pages
|
----categories
-----------index.js
-----------[id].js
```

For example if an ID does not exist in the database, how to pre-check if does not exists return 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the getServerSideProps
check for the data, and if data does not exists:

```
  if (!categories) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
```

This will return to the 404 file.

Answer (score 1):

I would fetch for data on your front-end, if data exists display the page if not redirect to your 404 error page.